# Tilde (~) in WMI string query

Tags: mysql, string, wmi, wql

```
WqlQuery="SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem WHERE (Manufacturer &gt;= 'ABC' AND Manufacturer &lt; 'ABC~' )"`.
```

Here in this `Wql Query` what does `Manufacturer &lt; 'ABC~'`, in `ABC~` what is `~` doing.

Work Done-
The complete query will search for a string that starts with `ABC."STARTS WITH"` can also be used in place of string comparison. But here in this case what would happen beacuse of `~`.

Comment: Can you say where you have this code sample from?

Comment: He wants to include strings such as `ABC*` up to `ABC}` and exclude from `ABC~` and after. May be `ABC~` and later strings have a special meaning, or may be he just wanted to use `< 'ABD'`. I am guessing using > and < is faster than using a function (operators should be faster than functions).

Comment: @SalmanA The fact that there is `&gt;=` and not `<=` means with some certainty that the WQL was copied off of some broken website.

Comment: I wonder if it even runs. `&gt;=` is `>=` by the way and I needed to look closely.